# Django 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'completed_todo'

Tags: python, django, wsgi, django-wsgi

I get an error `WSGIRequest` object has no attribute `completed_todo` when I go to a link in my Django project

Here it is my code:

My models.py:

```
class Todo(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Todo"
        verbose_name_plural = "Todos"


class CompletedTodo(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

My views.py:

```
class Comp:


def complete_todo(self, todo_id):
    self.todo_id = todo_id
    completed_text = Todo.objects.get(id=todo_id).text
    completed_date = Todo.objects.get(id=todo_id)

    completed_todo = CompletedTodo.objects.create(text=completed_text, date=completed_date)
    self.completed_todo = completed_todo
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

def completed_tasks(self):
    context = {'todo': self.request.completed_todo}
    return render(self, 'main/completed_tasks.html', context)
```

My urls.py:

```
path('completed_tasks', views.Comp.completed_tasks, name='completed_tasks'),
path('complete_todo/<int:todo_id>', views.Comp.complete_todo, name='complete_todo')
```

The error that I get:

```
    WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'request'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/completed_tasks
Django Version: 3.0.8
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'request'
Exception Location: D:\Edgar\IT\Programming\django\projects\Todo App\todo\main\views.py in completed_tasks, line 49
Python Executable:  D:\Edgar\IT\Programming\django\projects\Todo App\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.3
```

Comment: `self` is here the `request` object, so `self.complete_todo` makes not much sense.

Comment: Without self I get an error: name 'completed_tasks' is not defined

Comment: you should not remove the `self` parameter. You should simply remove the `self.request`, and use `self`, (or rename `self` to `request` and use `request` instead of `self.request`).